# Elasticsearch still hit multi shards with routing field specified when querying

Tags: elasticsearch, routes

[Search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68MPX.png)

I'm new in Elasticsearch. As result return from the es query above. It confuse me that, the query still hit 20 shards(48 shards in total) after given the routing value, instead of 1. So,How can I understand "_shards" field of the returned result, even the routing process?

Comment: Is that custom routing value you used in search query ?

Comment: em~ I do not place the routing field inside query body but  treat it as an url parameter and keep the custom routing value the same as the query condition :)

Comment: I see that but why are you expecting your search query to hit only 1 shard ? Did you use the custom routing value to index that particular document ? By default _id is used as a routing value when indexing data. See https://www.elastic.co/blog/customizing-your-document-routing

Comment: Yes, I only set _routing equals to "key" during index period, but do not add "_routing" as required  when configuring mapping(is that necessary?). I'm now using es 6.4 and indexing data by stream_bulk() provided by python client. thanks~

Comment: em~ I have figured out the problem that I did not specify the index and type inside the request url carelessly，which turn out be correct after given. thanks @ben5556 for your attention~